# Add column to ASP.net Gridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What is the C# code (code behind) for adding a column to grdview in asp.net ...something equivalent to this :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Last Name" 
             HeaderText="Last Name" 
             SortExpression="LastName" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
boundfield.DataField = "Last Name";
boundfield.HeaderText = "Last Name";
boundfield.SortExpression= "LastName";
GridView1.Columns.Add(boundfield);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
var column = new BoundField();
column.DataField = "LastName";
column.HeaderText = "Last Name";
column.SortExpression = "LastName";
GridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var boundColumn = new BoundField();
                boundColumn.DataField = "LastName";
                boundColumn.HeaderText = "Last Name";
                boundColumn.SortExpression = "LastName";
                GVPictures.Columns.Add(boundColumn);                
                BindGridView();
            }
        }
```